# What is this line on water?

Tags: everyday-life, atmospheric-science, weather

What is this line on water? What causes this difference in appearance? I often see it on lakes. Not sure if it appears in the sea too.

[image]

Comment: Possible dupplicate: [Why does the lake surface appear darker in some areas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176537/why-does-the-lake-surface-appear-darker-in-some-areas)

Comment: As a former sailor of small boats on lakes, I would call that a "puff of wind."  The variations that you see in the surface texture are variations in size and spatial frequencies of waves.  The waves are caused by wind interacting with the surface, and the wind is swirling around in huge invisible vortices that are caused by its interaction with the surrounding land.