# Why do water surfaces have persistent "average wavelength" patches?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water, frequency, wavelength

[image: Wavelength patches on water surface][image: Wavelength patches on water surface]

Have you ever stood above a river or lake and noticed that the surface has visible "patches"? It looks like the surface has different average wavelengths in some areas, leading to the light being reflected differently (more vs less shiny).

Something has puzzled me for a long time. These patches are quite stable. Their shape changes minimally even over a time of minutes. This is clearly a muh longer timescale than the average wave periods, for both the longer and the shorter waves.

Even further, you would expect that at a spatial scale comparable to the small wavelengths, a small wavelength patches boundary would change quite rapidly. But even that doesn't exactly seem to be the case, as far as I can tell.

I unfortunately don't have a video depicting this.

Here are some possble explanations I have personally ruled out:

- Cloud shadows would not create sharp patches
- The same holds true for srface structures like poles or trash
- At some point I suspected oil patches to be the explanation since boats create these patches in their wake, but it doesn't really make sense that there would be so much oil everywhere.

The best explanation I can think of is that this is just how water waves behaves in regards to the spread of waves and wavelengtg w.r.t. spatial and temporal scales.

Perhaps one could demonstrate this surprising long time persistence of avelength patches in an approximate linear system?

Or could there be some true nonlinear stability effects at play?

EDIT: Note that this question is not one of the following:

- Why are there waves (wind)
- Why does the water look darker and brighter (reflectivity due to waves)

The question is about the surprising persistence and localization of these patches.

The best explanation given so far has been a comment saying it is oil. This being the most likely correct answer shows that this question is different from the above similar ones.

I am still a bit skeptical that the oil would be localized so much.

Comment: most likely wind driven

Comment: The appearance of waves and patches in general is surely due to the wind, but for me the wind does not explain the persistence.

Comment: these short (relative to depth) wavelength surface waves are very dispersive and unless are being driven they do not go far and quickly disappear, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_wave and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)

Comment: “*it doesn't really make sense that there would be so much oil everywhere.*” Why? I see oil-using boats everywhere. [It doesn’t take much](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3552257/).

Comment: @Chemomechanics I mean you have surely seen patches as in my photo before. Do you really think it's oil?

Comment: @hyportnex well yes the wind generates waves, but it does not generate waves localized to a patch a couple of square meters in size.

Comment: Yes, these look like areas of relative smoothness resulting from oil resting on the surface. [Pop-sci explanation video](https://youtu.be/f2H418M3V6M?si=8RpHMi-YUewIrFpf).

Comment: That is pretty convincing, I think they're oil patches now. That's fascinating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the lake surface appear darker in some areas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176537/)

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with oil, this is quite typical even for rivers or lakes without boats. Rather, there are probably two effects: (a) Wind creates eddies which lead to rougher, darker water surface locally -- in your photo, wind is probably from the right, so the right part of the river is shielded by the slope. (b) Turbulence in the water (not just the surface)  suppresses wave formation, so the wakes of ships (turbulent due to the propellers) are less rough, hence lighter.

Comment: @Toffomat at which timescales would you expect these structures to persist? I would imagine that these small eddies created locally by some wind should spread out and disperse. But the shapes visible in the picture are persistent over minutes!

Comment: These eddies can easily (more or less) stay in a place for minutes, if the wind is generally steady and tehre is some obstacle. They may also move with the gusts - when you're sailing, you learn too look out for those patches because they tell you where the wind is.

Comment: Note that I would guess that the lighter "lanes" in your seocnd picture are wakes behind a ship, maybe one that's turning